# Laravel - getting largest object based on attribute value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have been trying to get the four highest objects based on an attribute in them.

I can successfully get the one with the highest value by doing the following:

```
{{ Bid::where('auction_id', '=', $auction->id)->max('bid_amount') }}
```

Which gets the object which have the highest `bid_amount` value.

Now I could potentially make a loop and loop all bids through but Laravel must have a smarter way of doing it and I have not been able to find this in their documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
Bid::where('auction_id', '=', $auction->id)
    ->orderBy('bid_amount', 'DESC')
    ->take(4)
    ->get();
```