# Laravel 4 and Eloquent ORM - How to select the last 5 rows of a table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to figure out how to select the last 5 rows of a table to display on a home screen when there might be gaps in the ids. The database this is for has 1,000s of rows and I don't want to have to call all of them to take the last 5 every time I go to my app's home screen. The problem is that rows sometimes are deleted in the database for various reasons so, for example, if the last row's id is 4023 the second to last row's id might be 4020, so I can't just use the length and count backwards. Ideally it would work like

```
$get_5_rows = DB::table('rows')->take(5)->get();
```

Except that instead of collecting the first 5 rows that it would take the last 5.

Thank y'all so much for the help! Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$rows = DB::table('rows')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
```

You may also use `orderBy('created_at')` if that field is available. Another similar [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835362/laravel-getting-largest-object-based-on-attribute-value/19835554#19835554).

Comment: Thanks! I think you meant "('rows')->orderBy", and that worked perfectly! I'll accept the answer in a few minutes when it allows me to.

Comment: @TheAlpha I think there is an error on your edit: `('rows')->->orderby`