# How do I return last n records in the order of entry

Tags: laravel, eloquent

From [Laravel 4 and Eloquent ORM - How to select the last 5 rows of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300062/laravel-4-and-eloquent-orm-how-to-select-the-last-5-rows-of-a-table), but my question is a little different.

How do I return **last N records** ordered in the way they were created (ASC).

So for example the following records are inserted in order:

```
first
second
third
fourth
fifth
```

I want a query to return last 2 records

```
fourth
fifth
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Laravel Offset**

`DB::table('users')->skip(<NUMBER Calulation>)->take(5)->get();`

You can calculate N by getting the count of the current query and skipping $query->count() - 5 to get the last 5 records or whatever you wanted.

Ex

```
$query = User::all();
$count = ($query->count()) - 5;

$query = $query->skip($count)->get();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Does this have **major** performance impact?

Comment: No not at all since you will already be making the exact same query.  Just add onto it.  I have included a example in my code.  Remember just to build on top of the query and not make 2 queries to the DB

Comment: @Rafael Your second example in fact runs 2 queries. First, fetching all records and then again when using `skip`.

Comment: :|  Yes I guess it is huh.  But that is the only way to do it.

Comment: @Rafael Yes it is. See my answer

Comment: @Angel.King.47 I see you accepted this answer. Please take a look at mine and see if it works. It's definitely better in terms of performance.

Comment: @lukasgeiter I am using mongodb so yours wont work for that. Would it?

Answer (score 1):

In pure SQL this is done by using a subquery. Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM foo
    ORDER BY created_at DES
    LIMIT 2
) as sub
ORDER BY created_at ASC
```

So the limiting happens in the subquery and then in the main query the order by is reversed. Laravel doesn't really have native support for subqueries. However you can still do it:

```
$sub = DB::table('foo')->latest()->take(2);
$result = DB::table(DB::raw('(' . $sub->toSql() . ') as sub'))
            ->oldest()
            ->get();
```

And if you use Eloquent:

```
$sub = Foo::latest()->take(2);
$result = Foo::from(DB::raw('(' . $sub->toSql() . ') as sub'))
             ->oldest()
             ->get();
```

**Note** the `latest` and `oldest` just add an `orderBy('created_at)` with `desc` and `asc` respectively.